# Why does my Linux report "PCI-Express Device Error"?

Tags: linux-kernel

My Linux operating system reports the following errors frequently. I wonder what happens.

```
+------ PCI-Express Device Error ------+
Error Severity      : Corrected
PCIE Bus Error type : Data Link Layer
Bad TLP                 : Multiple
Receiver ID     : 801a
VendorID=8086h, DeviceID=3c0ah, Bus=80h, Device=03h, Function=02h
```

I've checked the code, and it comes from the file `kernel/drivers/pci/pcie/aer/aerdrv_errprint.c`, but I still wonder what it happens and how to solve this problem.

Comment: One of your PCI-E devices sends incorrectly formatted PCI-E packets.

Comment: @CL. so do you mean there are some problems with the hardware?